# running two GitLab pipelines with the same runner

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I have two pipelines that I want to run with the same runner, is it possible?

my single runner installed on a Linux virtual machine and I want to use it to run all my pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

If the pipelines are for different projects you will need to make sure the runner is accessible to each project.

Depending on the level of control you want, you can utilise gitlab cis keyword for tags, this will then enable you to determine which runner handles which pipeline.

If you want to run the jobs in parallel you will need to make sure the runner is enabled for concurrent running and also that the jobs are in the same stages within the pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to do this at the moment is to define one tag for one runner only and user this tag for your project.
This way everything is run on this single runner.

This has of course the disadvantage that the load is not spread to different runners, so be careful.

You could improve this solution if you a [child pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/downstream_pipelines.html#parent-child-pipelines) to get a new free runner tag and create a child pipeline using it.

There are active issues about this problem in gitlab, see [this one](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/118599) and [this](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab/-/issues/17497).

There is a [forum entry](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/easy-way-to-have-a-pipeline-executed-by-a-single-runner-or-how-to-keep-the-same-runner-for-all-jobs/63014/12) about it as well.